# issues building a color changing analog clock w/ javascript

Tags: javascript, css, clock

So I'm trying to teach myself JavaScript by building a google plugin. The idea is that each interval the color changes (seconds hand every 5 seconds, minute every 5 minutes etc.) but I'm having trouble. I've built the clock and aside from a few stylistic changes I think it's done just leaving this pesky javascript. So my first idea was to calculate the angles of the clock and create "zones" I guess for each color (when the seconds hand is between 12-1 or 30 degrees it is red, then 30 degrees later it changes to green then blue etc.). So this is all my html and css + the javascript that makes the clock work and the angle calculation.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Analog Clock</title>
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="clock1.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="analog-clock">
                <svg width="140" height="140">
                    <circle id="clock-face" cx="70" cy="70" r="65" />
                    <line id="h-hand" x1="70" y1="70" x2="70" y2="38" />
                    <line id="m-hand" x1="70" y1="70" x2="70" y2="20" />
                    <line id="s-hand" x1="70" y1="70" x2="70" y2="12" />
                    <text x="62" y="18">12</text>
                    <text x="126" y="76">3</text>
                    <text x="66" y="130">6</text>
                    <text x="7" y="76">9</text>
                </svg>
                <div class="time-text">
                    <span id="hr">:</span>
                    <span></span>
                    <span id="min">:</span>
                    <span></span>
                    <span id="sec">:</span>
                    <span id="suffix"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
          </body>
         </html>



       *{
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            font-family:sans-serif;
            font-size:14px;
        }

    .analog-clock{
        width:140px;
        height:140px;
    }

    #clock-face{
        stroke:black;
        stroke-width:2px;
        fill:transparent;
    }

    #h-hand, #m-hand, #s-hand {
        stroke:black;
        stroke-linecap:round;
    }

    #h-hand{
        stroke-width:3px;
    }

    #m-hand{
        stroke-width:2px;
    }

    #s-hand{
        stroke-width:1px;
    }

    .time-text{
        text-align:center;
    }





    function clock(){
            //calculate angle
            var d, h, m, s;
            d = new Date;

            h = 30 * ((d.getHours() % 12) + d.getMinutes() / 60);
            m = 6 * d.getMinutes();
            s = 6 * d.getSeconds();

            //move hands
            setAttr('h-hand', h);
            setAttr('m-hand', m);
            setAttr('s-hand', s);
            setAttr('s-tail', s+180);

            //display time
            h = d.getHours();
            m = d.getMinutes();
            s = d.getSeconds();

           // necessary? if(h >= 12){
           //     setText('suffix', 'PM');
          //  }else{
          //      setText('suffix', 'AM');
           // }

            if(h != 12){
                h %= 12;
            }

            //setText('sec', s);
           // setText('min', m);
           // setText('hr', h);

            //call every second
            setTimeout(clock, 1000);

        };

        function setAttr(id,val){
            var v = 'rotate(' + val + ', 70, 70)';
            document.getElementById(id).setAttribute('transform', v);
      };

            function setText(id,val){
                if(val < 10){
                    val = '0' + val;
                }
                document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = val;
            };

            const colors = ['black', 'blue', 'red', 'green', 'pink', 'orange', 'yellow', 'purple', 'black', 'silver', 'gold', 'brown', 'gray', 'blue', 'red', 'pink', 'magenta', 'orange', 'black'];
function getColorTerse() {
  const now = new Date();
  const minutes = now.getMinutes();
  const interval = Math.floor(minutes/5);
  return colors[interval];
}

const color = getColorTerse();
const attribute = 'stroke: ' + color;
document.getElementById('m-hand').setAttribute('style', attribute);

            //var hand = document.getElementById("h-hand")?
            //var handm = document.getElementById("m-hand")?
            //var hands = document.getElementById("s-hand")?
```

and then here is what I have so far to calculate the angles.

```
function testColor(){
   var ang;
   var num;
   for(num = 1; num < 13; num++){
    ang = num * Math.PI / 6;
}
```

so I've been stuck here for awhile and I'm running out of ideas (I tried a whole setInterval thing but that's a mess too) so I guess I just want to know if it's possible to assign color values to an angle on the clock, and then the minute/hour/second hand will change to that color when it is in that angle. Is there a way to compose like an if/else statement or while loop? Bust basically the biggest thing is can I even assign color values to those angles or should I pursue a different strategy?

Edit: So I added in the suggested code. I decided to test it out on the hour, second and minute hand and got the same result. The color is assigned when the clock is loaded but it doesn't change color unless you refresh the page

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to calculate the color based on the current time, rather than on the position of the hands?

Comment: @GuillaumeCR possibly, I haven't explored that option yet. is it possible to build it that way using JS? like I said above i'm using this to learn javascript

Answer (score 1):

The same way that you are drawing your hands based on the current time, you should determine the color based on that time as well. This is an important notion in programming where you want to base your logic on a model, not on UI elements.

Here's some javascript to get you started.

```
function getColor() {
  const now = new Date();
  const minutes = now.getMinutes();
  switch (Math.floor(minutes/5)) {
    case 0:
      return 'black';
      break;
    case 1:
      return 'blue';
      break;
      //etc
    default:
      return 'red';
      break;
  }
}
```

This is a good example of how to use switch, but as you'll find out it will get very long if you have 20 different intervals. The following code accomplishes the same thing, but uses an array instead.

```
const colors = ['black', 'blue', 'red', 'green', 'etc', 'but', 'make', 'sure', 'you', 'have', '20', 'elements', 'in', 'there', 'or', 'it', 'will', 'return', 'undefined!'];
function getColorTerse() {
  const now = new Date();
  const minutes = now.getMinutes();
  const interval = Math.floor(minutes/5);
  return colors[interval];
}
```

You can then use this function like so:

```
const color = getColorTerse();
const attribute = 'stroke: ' + color;
document.getElementById('h-hand').setAttribute('style', attribute);
```

Comment: so I plugged that in but I'm having trouble getting the hands to change colors. I tried using the var hand/var hands/var handm I commented out in my original post. then I tried plugging in the hand/s/m in getColorTerse but no luck.

Comment: @amnmustafa15 So there is a difference between declaring a function and executing it. Are you sure your code is being executed? Use chrome's dev tools with a debugger breakpoint to make sure. Post an updated version of your code and tell us exactly what problem you're encountering.

Comment: @amnmustafa15 Edited my answer to show how to use the function.

Comment: I made the edits you suggested. The color is assigned when the page loads but does not change color at the intervals. The only way to change the color is to refresh the page.

Comment: @amnmustafa15 Update your question with the new code.